# Array looping - cannot get key to print

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have an array as follows in $newarray

```
Array
(
    [111] => Array
        (
            [123] => 0
            [124] => 0
            [125] => 0
            [126] => 0
            [127] => 0
            [128] => 0
            [129] => 0
            [130] => 1
            [131] => 1
            [132] => 1
            [133] => 1
            [134] => 1
            [135] => 1
        )

    [222] => Array
        (
            [123] => 0
            [124] => 0
            [125] => 0
            [126] => 1
            [127] => 1
            [128] => 1
            [129] => 1
            [130] => 1
            [131] => 1
            [132] => 1
            [133] => 1
            [134] => 1
            [135] => 1
        )

    [333] => Array
        (
            [256] => 0
            [321] => 0
            [456] => 0
            [489] => 0
            [652] => 1
            [741] => 1
            [965] => 0
        )

)
```

I need to grab the key names (111, 222 and 333 in this case) in a foreach:

The following always spits out "222" 3 times, regardless of what I do. Anything obvious?

```
foreach($newarray as $value) {
echo key($newarray) . "<br />";
}
```

Output

```
222
222
222
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
foreach($newarray as $key => $value)
{
     echo $key . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Thanks both. So the problem I have in using the $arr as $key => $value method is it doesn't work with another nested foreach. Within each foreach loop I then do a `foreach ($value as $value2)` so I can grab the next array's key and value (so 123 and 0 in the first example). When I change the foreach method and the var names accordingly it doesn't work.

Comment: @Dan It should work just fine - what output are you getting, and what are you expecting? What does your code look like? If you use `foreach ($newarray as $key=>$value)`, you should still be using the `$value` variable (this is your next-level array) in the next foreach as so: `foreach ($value as $key2=>$value2)`.

Answer (score 4):

This is the correct way to use foreach

```
foreach($newarray as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key . "<br />";
}
```

or you can use

```
print_r(array_keys($newarray));
```